# Convert tuple of unknown length to List in Scala

Tags: scala

I need a method which will receive tuple of unknown length (Tuple2, Tuple3 or TupleX) and return list of tuple elements. I wrote the following method, but I get an error that it cannot cast type `Any` to `String` in the List:

```
def toList(tuple: Product): List[String] = tuple match {
  case (s1, s2) => List(s1, s2)
  case (s1, s2, s3) => List(s1, s2, s3)
}
```

Could you please help to fix above example or propose another solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All `TupleN` type inherit from `Product`, and `Product` has the method `productIterator` ([documentation link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Product.html)), so you can write:

```
def toList(tuple: Product): List[String] = 
  tuple.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]).toList
```

Note that this is not type safe. It will throw errors whenever your are passing anything that is not a tuple of `String`s to it. You might want to call `_.toString` instead.

Comment: Just a minor note, but `map(...).toList` instead of the other way around will avoid intermediate list construction.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this if you are not sure that your input is string or something else:

`def toList(tuple: Product): List[String] = {`
  `tuple.productIterator.map(_.toString).toList`
`}`

`toList("1",2,3.0)`

The above method works for String, Int, Double as you may see above.