# Iterating nested map gives error in scala

Tags: scala

Format : **(UserId->((Movie1Id,Rating),(Movie2Id,Rating)))**

I wanted to print Movie1Id and Movie2Id.

Following code works fine:

```
  user foreach (x => println (x._2._1))
```

Following Code doesn't work:

```
 val col1 = Map(645-> ((1->3.5),(2->5.2)))
 println(col1._2._1)
```

Error:

```
 value _2 is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,((Int,  Double),(Int, Double))]
   user._2._1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need `Map` of `Map` then you should write:

```
val col1 = Map(645-> Map(1->3.5,2->5.2), 644 -> Map(1->3.5,2->5.2))
col1 foreach (user => user._2 foreach (mov => println(mov._1)))
```

Then your type will be `Map[Int, Map[Int, Double]]`.

Otherwise, your data type, is not nested `Map`, but `Map` of `Tuple` of `Tuple`, i.e. `Map[Int, ((Int, Double), (Int, Double))]. Then you have to convert your inside tuple to list in order to iterate over it.

```
val col1 = Map(645-> ((1->3.5),(2->5.2)), 644 -> ((1->3.5),(2->5.2)))
// one liner
col1 foreach (user => user._2.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[(Int, Double)]).toList.foreach(mov => println(mov._1)))

// long version
col1 foreach (user => {
  // make list from tuple
  val movies = user._2.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[(Int, Double)]).toList
  // iterate over list
  movies foreach(mov => println(mov._1))
})
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

For your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149070/convert-tuple-of-unknown-length-to-list-in-scala).

EDIT: extracting ratings:

```
// each user
println(col1.map(user => user._2.values.toList))
// output: List(List(3.5, 5.2), List(3.5, 5.2))

// for specific user
println(col1.get(645).map(_.values.toList))
// output: Some(List(3.5, 5.2)) or None if user key does not exist

// if you are sure that user exists
// but this will throw exception if user does not exist
// better to go with get option
println(col1(645).values.toList)
// output: List(3.5, 5.2) or exception if user key does not exist
```

Comment: Hi @muradm .. Thanks for the above solution..But I was looking to extract the Rating id of first / second movie directly without using for each loop..Is there a solution possible ? Something like this : println(col1._2._1)

Answer (score 1):

So you have this ridiculous data representation.

```
val col1 = Map(645-> ((1->3.5),(2->5.2)))
```

And, for some inexplicable reason, you want to print the **Rating** data without traversing the `Map` using a `foreach` loop and the like.

Two options come to mind. One is to use the known key value directly.

```
println(col1(645)._1._2 + ", " + col1(645)._2._2)  //3.5, 5.2
```

Or you could take the `head` of the `Map` because, in this case, there is only one element in the `Map`.

```
println(col1.head._2._1._2 + ", " + col1.head._2._2._2)  //3.5, 5.2
```